# ActionController::UnknownFormat in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Here is my index controller below:

```
def index
    paginated = paginate(Coin.recent)
    render_collection(paginated)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do 
        format.html # index.html.erb        
        format.json { render json: render_collection(paginated) }
      end
    end
  end
```

I'm trying to create logic that handles both html and json, so that it can act as a json api and a view renderer.

Any ideas?

Comment: where are you stuck exactly? it would help if you explained what's missing/wrong in your code

Comment: I'm stuck at the respond_to do |format|. The error keeps point to this line: 
ActionController::RespondToMismatchError (respond_to was called multiple times and matched with conflicting formats in this action. Please note that you may only call respond_to and match on a single format per action.):
  
app/controllers/coins_controller.rb:11:in `index'

Comment: is it not your render_collection which make a respond_to ? You should provide the full backtrace

Comment: Here is the back trace of the application:                                                              
actionpack (6.1.3.1) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:216:in `respond_to'
app/controllers/coins_controller.rb:10:in `index'

Comment: get rid of ` format.json do `

Comment: Now I get this error:app/controllers/concerns/paginable.rb:27:in `render_collection'
app/controllers/coins_controller.rb:11:in `block in index'
app/controllers/coins_controller.rb:10:in `index' It looks like it's because I have my format.json inside the respond_to block. But when I remove it, I still get an error. How should I rewrite this code to make it work inside the index controller?

Comment: Can you post the code of `render_collection` method?

Comment: Here is my render_collection method:                                                                               
  def render_collection(paginated)
    options =
      {
        meta: paginated.meta.to_h,
        links: paginated.links.to_h
      }
      result = serializer.new(paginated.items, options)
    render json: result, status: :ok
  end

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys so I found out the solution to my problem:

```
def index
    paginated = paginate(Coin.recent)
    # render_collection(paginated)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        render_collection(paginated)
      end
      format.html do
        render :index
      end
    end
  end
```

I had commented out the render_collection(paginated) and then added json and html to it's own block and it worked.